# How to sometimes but not always add a note to an Org TODO state change?

Tags: org-mode

I have this in an Org mode projects file:

```
#+TODO: TODO(t!) WAITING(w!) DONE(d!) CANCELED(c@)
```

When I move something from TODO to WAITING, it adds a timestamp without asking for a note.  That's fine 8 or 9 times out of 10 ... but sometimes I want to add a note too.

If I use the @ it will always ask me for a note, and I have to `C-c C-c` to get out of that.  I'd like to avoid that if I can.

Is there a way (a prefix or alternate command) that I can use to have Org let me add an optional note when I change a TODO state?

`C-c C-z` (`org-add-note`) adds a note, but it does it to the item as a whole, not to the WAITING workflow change, like so:

```
* WAITING Find out how to sometimes add a note when I change to WAITING
  - Note taken on [2014-09-23 Tue 11:36] \\
    Asked on SE
  - State "WAITING"    from "WAITING"    [2014-09-23 Tue 11:30]
  - State "WAITING"    from "TODO"       [2014-09-21 Sun 11:25]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, note that passing a argument of 0 to `org-todo` would inhibit notes. So if you're willing to inverse the default state of everything, it might work for you.

But it'd be cleaner to force a note, which does not have a similar flag, unfortunately.

Here's something you can do to simulate that.

```
(defun org-todo-force-notes ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((org-todo-log-states
         (mapcar (lambda (state)
                   (list state 'note 'time))
                 (apply 'append org-todo-sets))))
    (call-interactively 'org-todo)))

(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-S-t") 'org-todo-force-notes)
```

Explanation: Here I'm temporarily redefining the note-taking semantic that's associated with all todo keywords (they're organized in sets in `org-todo-sets`, a flat representation might be available in another variable) to force note-taking, and passing that as a dynamic context to the actual `org-todo` code.
So whenever hitting `C-c C-T` (uppercase T), you force a note, regardless of what state you'll end up with.